# static variable set to default value on removing Android app

Tags: android, service, android-service, static-members, android-lifecycle

I have an Android app which relies alot on background services. I am getting some values from c++ through JNI in the service and setting those values to some static variables.

As far my understanding, the values should be kept in those variables even if App is removed as Services stays ON all the time in background. But somehow when app is removed or killed, the static variables are resetting back to default values instead of having new assigned values.

Can any body explain me the behavior of static variable in background services in Android. Thanks. Here is code

```
public class ServiceData extends Service{
  public static void setUser_id(int id) {
    user_id = id;
}

public static void setUserData_id(int id) {
user_data_id = id;
}

protected static int user_id = -1;
protected static int user_data_id = -1;


@Override public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

context = getApplicationContext();

running = true;
Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate");
Toast.makeText(context,"in onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Log.d(TAG, "in onStartCommand");
Toast.makeText(context,"in onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return START_STICKY;
}

@Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
Log.d(TAG, "in onBind");
Toast.makeText(context,"in onBind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return messenger.getBinder();
}

@Override public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
Log.d(TAG, "in onUnbind");
Toast.makeText(context,"in onUnBind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);

//return true;
}

@Override public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
Log.d(TAG, "in onRebind");
Toast.makeText(context,"in onRebind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     super.onRebind(intent);
}

@Override public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
Log.d(TAG, "in onDestrory");
Toast.makeText(context,"in onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    this.manager.cancel(R.string.service_started);

    running = false;
}
```

Comment: You should use SharedPreferences instead static variables.

Comment: yes but I do not want to use sharedPreference ...I guess this should work too...

Comment: Yes but some times on app crashed  static variable set to default.

Comment: so there is no other option then using permanent storage method

Comment: i think sharedpreference or you can use text file to store those variables another thing you may also use database but its little lenghy. so i suggest sharedpreference is best way to store global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think in android when user forcefully kill app all service of particular app are also killed .if you want to store the value throughout app you can use shared preferences in android.

Comment: Services stays on even if user kills app..in my cases services are on all time..only issue is with values stored in static values

Answer (score 0):

static variable's are called class variable and in way of scope they loaded when the class is loaded and unloaded when class is unloaded. When the app is removed they will not be available. Instead of using static variable,use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only time you can set a static variable is in its parent class constructor. Are you sure they are defined as static? show some code.

Comment: I added the code..in user_id and user_data_id gets to -1 when I removed app and it is my sevice

Comment: If onDestroy is being called then you're going to lose reference to those variables regardless. Look into the application class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html the simple answer is to use shared prefs though, just load them onCreate and set them as non static variables

Comment: I checked with Toast this onDestroy is not getting called and I am using START_STICKY which is not allowed to call onDestory()